What does lastsend and lastrecv in "getpeerinfo" rpc mean?
The Bitcoin Core RPC docs says lastsend as UNIX epoch time of last send, similarly for lastrecv. Does that mean last sent/received P2P message or transaction?

These are the timestamps of the last time any byte was sent or received to/from the peer over the P2P connection.
The distinction between bytes and messages matters for large messages, such a blocks. On a slow connection, a block may take multiple seconds to send or to be received.

Got it! Thanks!!!
